# how the apps like whatsapp is running as the background service which are not killed by the android system

Tags: android, service, firebase-cloud-messaging, whatsapp, background-service

how the background services in whatsapp, facebook, instagram are running even if the app is closed in android versions >=N. also please suggest how to approach this problem

I am trying to get the current GPS location and update in server as a background service

(Note : I am using Gionee-X1 (Android-N), MI-MA4 (Android-N))

I have tried Foreground notification which is killed after 5 to 10 minutes in Gionee mobile and instantly in MI mobiles,

Also tried Ignore Battery optimization worked partially in some mobiles and not worked in MI Mobiles

Tried alaram manager, not working properly after the app is cleared

Tried Work Manager, PeriodicRequests is not working, OneTimeRequests with delay is worked upt 10 minutes in Gionee Mobile (When i configured periodic requests, it executed nearly 6 times within a second and not executed after that)

Finally, I need a piece of code or a procedure which should run a background service (also foreground service) and not to be killed by system when the app is closed or cleared from background.Also please tell how to implement service has to be restarted if system kills the service

Comment: *please suggest how to approach this problem* - make an app with a billion users, collect a lot of user data, become friends with google, get placed on a special whitelist

Comment: Hello Tim Castelijns, is there any programatical idea

Answer (score 0):

Need to disable "Battery Saver" process, to run your app continously .. In MI (My version is Redmi Note 8 Pro), navigate to Settings->Apps->Manage Apps->(select your app)->Battery Saver->(then set "No Restrictions")..